# How can I fly the camera in 2.8?

Tags: animation

I want to use the fly camera navigation in Blender 2.8, but I don't know how to do it. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> doesn't work. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortcut is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> or you can use the menu *View > Navigation > Fly Navigation*

[image: Menu]

If you're looking for a shortcut you can search for them in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*). They are searchable by name and key combination, depending what you've selected in the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: You can also easily get to it via the Operators list by pressing F3 and typing ‘fly’.